# Datepicker issue when implementing in mvc3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using `Mvc3` razor.
I tried to implement the Jquery data picker with an inputbox on my form, I am getting this exception "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property '`currentDay`': `object` is `null` or `undefined`" when I click on a date on the calendar.

**Jquery**:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {           
      $(".datepicker").datepicker();
 });
```

**Html** :

```
<div class='answer'>
  <input class='datepicker' type='text' id='4' name='4' value='' />
</div>
```

Comment: do you need a date set in the value attribute for when the datepicker appears? try rendering it with today's date for starters, or hardcoding in a dd/mm/yyyy value so it looks something like <input class='datepicker' type='text' id='4' name='4' value='01/01/2013' />

Comment: I tried <input class='datepicker' type='text' id='4' name='4' value='1/25/2013' /> ...still getting the same error?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the date field has a same id of another input field. They need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple test your code works outside of the MVC3 framework, so I would check the versions of JQuery/JQuery UI being included when the page is actually rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution for this error

solution is
we need to provide unique ids